# Searching patterns within txt file with post-processing

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed

I have a long txt files consisted of

```
ATOM   5010 HD13 LEU   301       0.158  20.865  10.630  1.00  0.00      PROA
ATOM   5011  CD2 LEU   301       1.684  22.404  12.349  1.00  1.00      PROA
ATOM   5012 HD21 LEU   301       2.233  22.501  13.310  1.00  0.00      PROA
ATOM   5013 HD22 LEU   301       1.584  23.412  11.894  1.00  0.00      PROA
ATOM   5014 HD23 LEU   301       2.267  21.744  11.672  1.00  0.00      PROA
ATOM   5015  C   LEU   301      -0.687  23.995  15.639  1.00  0.00      PROA
ATOM   5016  O   LEU   301      -1.791  24.341  15.139  1.00  0.00      PROA
ATOM   5017  NT  LEU   301      -0.211  24.391  16.849  1.00  1.00      PROA
ATOM   5018  HT1 LEU   301       0.679  24.065  17.168  1.00  0.00      PROA
ATOM   5019  HT2 LEU   301      -0.752  25.007  17.422  1.00  0.00      PROA
ATOM   5020  SOD SOD   302       1.519   2.284   1.361  1.00  0.00      HETA
```

From this file I need to copy the string where the third column = SOD

```
  ATOM   5020  SOD SOD   302       1.519   2.284   1.361  1.00  0.00      HETA
```

And past it to the separate txt file sod.txt (it should consist only one line which is equl to the original)

I could use a solution via combination of `awk` and `sed` commands!

Comment: `awk '$3 == "SOD"{print > "output.txt"}' file`

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sed write(`w` command):

```
sed '/\([^ \t]*\)\{2\}SOD/!d; w outputfile' file
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk '$3=="SOD"' file # > new_file # uncomment to write to a new file
ATOM   5020  SOD SOD   302       1.519   2.284   1.361  1.00  0.00      HETA
```

Comment: Thanks! And how to adapt it for a multiple case - e.g when I am looking for the strings with the third column == A or ==B and put them in a new file keeping its order from the original file ?

Comment: `$3=="A" || $3=="B"` where `||` is OR.

Comment: actually `$3 ~ /^(SOD|A|B)$/` so you don't need to keep repeating `$3 ==`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
awk '{if ($3 == "SOD") print $0;}' input.txt >sod.txt
```